# Starting node js application using grunt on machine start up

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, debian

I am new to both linux and Node js basically we have developed Node js application in Windows and I need to deploy it on Debian 8 Jessie and I am able to deploy it on linux and for this I need to install npm, node js, grunt cli etc.
And to run my application I just need to type grunt using terminal and application starts.
But the problem I need to start server every time after reboot of system by typing grunt in terminal.

So need solution how can I start my application/server on machine start.
Also let me know how this stuff works!!.

Thanks

Comment: check [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: I installed pm2 when I typed the "pm2 start Gruntfile.js" then its not starting the application please let me know what to correct.

Comment: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Answer (score 0):

as always there is more than one way

**rc.local**

the prefered way. `rc.local` will be executed on system startup.
to edit the file use your favourite text-editor (e.g. nano) `nano /etc/rc.local` and add your script before the last line containing `exit 0`

```
/usr/bin/myscript -arg1 -arg2
exit 0
```

**cronjob**

if there is also the need for recurring tasks (e.g a daily backup), cronjob could be a good choice to keep things together.
Within your terminal type `sudo crontab -e` to edit your cronjobs. 
there add your command with the @reboot time argument.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/myscript -arg1 -arg2
```